# Linux Libertine Biolinum xelatex and lualatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, small-caps, libertine

This is actually two questions rolled into one. Consider the example file below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O}]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[SmallCapsFont={Linux Biolinum Capitals O}]{Linux Biolinum O}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{sffamily}
\noindent Linux Biolinum sans serif text followed by {\scshape Sans serif Small Caps text.} {\scshape Small Caps disappear when diacritics are used like a macron above a in anāchron: note the small letter for the ā instead of a Small Caps version.}
\end{sffamily}

\medskip

\noindent Linux Libertine serif text followed by {\scshape Sans serif Small Caps text.} {\scshape Small Caps disappear when diacritics are used like a macron above a in anāchron: note the small letter for the ā instead of a Small Caps version.}
\end{document}
```

It compiles with `xelatex` but not with `lualatex.` My `fontspec` package gives
`\ProvidesPackage{fontspec}
  [2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX]`

The installation is on a 64-bit daily-updated TeX Live 2011 installation.

With `lualatex` I get this error:

```
! Improper `at' size (0.0pt), replaced by 10pt.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.10 ...inum sans serif text followed by {\scshape
                                                   Sans serif Small Caps tex...
```

Question 1: Why is the file failing to compile with lualatex?

Question 2: There is no small caps "a" with a macron in the PDF output. I just also noticed that the `tt` is not in small caps. [image: See this result]

I have reported this behaviour at the Linux Libertine project page, but in the absence of a response therefrom, I want to ensure that there is no usage error on my part.

Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you simplx use `\usepackage{libertineotf}`? It does all the font setting.

Comment: @Herbert: Thank you for the suggestion. I had tried only `\usepackage{libertine}` which did not work as expected. With `\usepackage{libertineotf}` though, I get _slanted_ small caps, not the upright version. But the file does compile with both `xelatex` and `lualatex`.

Comment: @Herbert Note that as stated on its [CTAN webpage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine), ***"the `libertine` pack­age [now] su­per­sedes both the `lib­erti­neotf` and the `lib­er­tine-legacy` pack­ages"***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Your document doesn't compile with XeLaTeX on my system, so I can't compare LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.*

There is a tiny problem in the code, but I am not the expert here:

```
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine Capitals O}]{Linux Libertine O}
```

With OpenType fonts the small caps are included in the main font. So there is no reason to explicitly mention a different one. Linux Libertine at least has them built in. Then there is no font `Linux Libertine Capitals O` on my system and I don't think that I have removed them explicitly.

Linux Libertine does not have a small caps ā in the font as far as I can see. And thus there is no way to display it. (You could fake it though.)

The problem with the small tt does not exist here, so I can't comment on that either. But I guess the correct answer is what Herbert commented:

> Why didn't you simply use `\usepackage{libertineotf}`? It does all the font setting.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}% ,Scale=MatchLowercase} bug in current Biolinum
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\begin{document}

\noindent Linux Libertine serif text followed by {\scshape Sans serif Small Caps text.} {\scshape Small Caps disappear when diacritics are used like a macron above a in anāchron: note the small letter for the ā instead of a Small Caps version.}

\medskip

\sffamily
\noindent Linux Biolinum sans serif text followed by {\scshape Sans serif Small Caps text.} {\scshape Small Caps disappear when diacritics are used like a macron above a in anāchron: note the small letter for the ā instead of a Small Caps version.}

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image: libertinesmallcaps]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works with *both* xelatex and lualatex and gives me the desired output. The `libertineotf` package seems to add slanted small caps instead of upright small caps as noted above. With your solution, I get an output exactly matching yours after removal of the superfluous text in brackets. I am using the Libertine font package version 5.1.3 from the home page of the font and there is no problem with `Scale=MatchLowercase` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oops! I spoke too soon. I *do* need to deselect `Scale=MatchLowercase` or Biolinum explodes in size with the `\fontsize` command. Thank you for solving a problem in anticipation, even before I experienced it.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[libertine={Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+onum},
            biolinum={Ligatures=TeX,RawFeature=+onum}]{libertineotf}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\noindent Linux Biolinum sans serif text followed by \Lsmcp{Sans serif Small Caps text.} \Lsmcp{Small Caps disappear when diacritics are used like a macron above a in anāchron: note the small letter for the ā instead of a Small Caps version.}
0123456

\medskip\rmfamily
\noindent Linux Libertine serif text followed by \Lsmcp{Sans serif Small Caps text.} \Lsmcp{Small Caps disappear when diacritics are used like a macron above a in anāchron: note the small letter for the ā instead of a Small Caps version.}
0123456
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to do it with `libertineotf`. This solution works fine too, both with `xelatex` and `lualatex`. It is a shame that only one answer is allowed per question.