# LuaLaTeX - Linux libertine (math and pgfplots)

Tags: fonts, pgfplots, amsmath, luatex

I have some problems using Linux libertine font within equations or pgfplots and tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49229/linux-libertine-biolinum-xelatex-and-lualatex) answer but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\begin{equation}
x = 4 \cdot 3 
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot {x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you say what the problems are other than saying "some problems"?

Comment: I had added a picture to show the problems.

Comment: I see the picture, but I still don't know what the problems are. Please be explicit, don't leave it to us to guess what the problems are.

Comment: In the picture are red marks. The numbers and any other symbols are in a different font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{libertine}%% lOADS ROMAN/SANS/MONO

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{equation}
x = 4 \cdot 3 
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot {x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{LinLibertineOI}
\setmathfont[range={\mathrm,0048-0057}]{LinLibertineO}

%% We now use Libertine for math characters    
\begin{equation}
x = 4 \cdot 3 
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot {x};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The x is different but the numbers are still the same.

Comment: see my edited answer, I'd forgotten the digits for `\mathrm`

Comment: Okay great it works but the \cdot is missing now.. and any other math symbols

Comment: Don't know the number for `\cdot`. Add it to the list. However, I suppose that nobody will see the difference .... ;-)

Comment: I've changed the range and it works now. Thank you very much! :)